# Clearing array without destructing the reference

Tags: ruby

I want to clear the array after declaring the hash value AND allow the hash value to remain intact.
Is that even possible?

```
hash = {}
number= "number"
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
hash[number]=array
```

This is the expected result, after clearing the array.

```
 {"number"=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]}
```

Comment: I want to clear the array, that way I can add new elements after they've been assigned to the hash.

Answer (score 5):

```
hash[number] = array.dup
array.clear
hash
 => {"number"=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

If your `array` contains just simple objects (as integers are), you can use `dup` method. Otherwise you need a deep copy.

Comment: Even with other objects chances are `dup` is the best choice, it is very unlikely that people ever want to clone objects inside an array.